# Расположение файла в приложении

Tags: java, android, ресурсы

В сиоу того что плохо знаком с java и android studio не знаю куда поместить его и как указать к нему путь, что бы на выходе не получить java.io.FileNotFoundException?

Код:

```
    public String print() {
    String not = "Not found";
    String help;
    String search = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            help = arr[i] + " ";
            search += help;
        } else {
            search += arr[i];
        }
    }
    try {
        // ПУТЬ К ФАЙЛУ НОРМАЛЬНЫЙ СДЕЛАЙ!!!
        String y = new Scanner(new File("res\\receptes\\none.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
        if (y.contains(search)) {
            return y;
            //System.out.println("File is contain your search:" + search);
            //System.out.println(y);
        } else {
            return not;
            //System.out.println("Your request did not found");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //System.out.println(e);
        return e.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: гляньте [тут](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html#java)

Comment: `как указать к нему путь` - что бы это могло значить? Я не знаю путь к файлу, но нужно указать путь? Это как вообще? - стоит добавить код. который вы уже написали и указать место ошибки.

Comment: @And да, моя формулировка подкачала. Наверное я имел в виду неполный путь. Код добавил в свой пост.